# Databricks error when trying to load a model

Tags: databricks, huggingface-transformers, mlflow

I am trying to train a model in databricks with mlflow and roberta transformers. I am able to register the model but when I call it for testing, I got the following error:

```
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co/' to load this model and it looks like dbfs:/databricks/mlflow-tracking/3638851642935524/cd4eae6034684211933b97b178e5f062/artifacts/checkpoint-36132/artifacts/checkpoint-36132 is not the path to a directory containing a config.json file.
```

However, when I check for the model saved, I can see that the config.json and other files are saved in the mentioned artifact but with the following error:

```
Couldn't load model information due to an error.
```

For more details, I have followed the following link for creating an mlflow with transformers on databricks:

https://gitlab.com/juliensimon/huggingface-demos/-/tree/main/mlflow

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading using an edited path, like so:
new_path = "/dbfs/rest_of_your_path"

I've found many times you have to switch between "dbfs:/" and "dbfs/"

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code that you are using to load the model from MLflow?

It looks like you are trying to specify the path to dbfs directly. The correct way to achieve it though is through the MLflow API.

You can refer to the blog post / example below - just replace the model with Roberta and you should be fine:

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/02/06/getting-started-nlp-using-hugging-face-transformers-pipelines.html